# jQuery using fadeOut to hide content and fadeIn a success repeats

Tags: jquery, append

I have a `li` with the classing `mailing-list` it has `h4` x3 `input[type=text]` and `span`

```
$('.mailing-list input').fadeOut();
$('.mailing-list span').fadeOut(function(){
    $('.mailing-list').append('<div><img src="/build/wp-content/themes/andersons/img/icons/tick.png"/></div>').hide().fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('.mailing-list input, .mailing-list span').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

When I combine the first 2 into

`$('.mailing-list span, .mailing-list input').fadeOut(function(){`

the appended content gets repeated 4 times

`<div><img src="/build/wp-content/themes/andersons/img/icons/tick.png"/></div>`

Is there a way to simplify my initial code?

**html**

```
<li class="mailing-list">
    <h4>Join our mailing list</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="input half subscribe-first">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" class="input half half-last subscribe-last"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" class="input subscribe-email">
    <span class="go subscribe-btn">GO</span>
</li>
```

The goal is to hide the `input` fields and `span` and leave the `H4` and fade in the div with `image`, delay 2 seconds then fadeout and fade back in the `inputs` and `span`

Comment: post your HTML it will help with the answer

Comment: After posting the html, describe what you're goal is without talking about the markup specifically. Example: I would like to fade the row and fade it back in with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code :

```
$(selector).fadeOut( callback );
```

the `callback` function will be called once for each individual node selected by `$(selector)`.
4 nodes -> 4 calls.

One way to have one single function call is to take advantage of the underlying `Promise` created by `fadeOut` :

```
$(selector).fadeOut().promise().done( callback );
// or
$.when( $(selector).fadeOut() ).done( callback );
```

With your code :

```
$.when($('.mailing-list span, .mailing-list input')).fadeOut()).done(function(){
    $('.mailing-list').append('<div><img src="/build/wp-content/themes/andersons/img/icons/tick.png"/></div>').hide().fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('.mailing-list input, .mailing-list span').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

However, it does not get much simpler than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code snippet it is fine and does not need simplifying.

If you combine the selectors as you describe then the [complete] callback function will get called for each matching element, of which there are four in this example.

As long as you only have one `<span>` element inside your `.mailing-list` block, the appending function will only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

Like many have already said, your targeting a collection of elements with `$('.mailing-list span')`, thus the callback from the animation is firing  just as many times.

Two ways to simplify your code:

1. wrapping your target content with a div - allowing you to add any number of elements to it later.
2. You could also have the `img` container already pre-loaded into the markup (hidden) so you don't have any markup in your JavaScript.

**Example HTML**

```
<li class="mailing-list">
    <h4>Join our mailing list</h4>
    <div class="mailing-list-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="input half subscribe-first">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" class="input half half-last subscribe-last"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" class="input subscribe-email">
        <span class="go subscribe-btn">GO</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mailing-list-confirmation" style="display:none"><img src="/build/wp-content/themes/andersons/img/icons/tick.png"/></div>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.mailing-list-content').fadeOut(function() {
    var $content = $('.mailing-list-content');
    $content.closest('.mailing-list').find('.mailing-list-confirmation').fadeIn(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(function() {
            $content.fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```